# Formatting an implication cycle proof

Tags: lists, environments, amsthm

Some theorems/lemmata/propositions start with "*If [...] then **the following are equivalent:***". After this, an enumeration *(i), (ii), (iii)* follows.  
[image: rough structure of lemma]

The proof is usually done in an "implication cycle": first prove (i)⇒(ii), then (ii)⇒(iii) and (iii)⇒(i).  
[image: proof structure]

The question is: What's the **right method to use for such proofs**?

1. Is there some kind of environment aside the obvious, like "\begin{description}"?
2. Best would be if the references (and labels) are created automatically.
3. Additionally, does this method also automatically change the numbering, for example if I change "*(i)*" to "*A.*"?

Comment: Please have you tried anything or the image is a scan of a textbook?

Comment: The image is a scan from a textbook.

Comment: This is about style, so off-topic for the site. I'd avoid the quotes and the colon, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: @egreg You are right at some point. My question is about style, but not only. My purpose is to find an easy way tackling the points 2 and 3, maybe there is a package I don't know about. If you still convinced the question shouldn't belong here, explain please, where to ask... 

I'd avoid the quotes and colons too; the images do not show, what I want to achieve, but what I noticed is the way of handling the problem at the moment.

Comment: Out of the box, latex can us `\label` on the lemma parts, and `\ref` in the proof parts.  Getting the implication to appear would be more difficult and probably not worth the trouble.  Especially since some proofs don't prove a cycle, but instead prove that (i) and (iii) are each equal to (ii).  For example, this image isn't proving (iii) => (i).

Comment: You are right, "(iii) => (ii)" is a mistake, "(iii) => (i)" is correct.